# Error on Laravel after installing VueJS. Request failed with status 404

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am developing a small system with Laravel Framework 5.6.39 and everything was going well, until I installed Vue Js. When viewing in the browser, what should be displayed does not appear and the following appears in the console:

[image]

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need  to run:

```
npm run watch
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding VueJS to your project you need to install all dependencies by executing:

```
npm install
```

Then you can either compile your assets onetime by executing:

```
npm run dev
```

Or start a watcher which compiles your assets automatically after detecting a filechange:

```
npm run watch
```

The compile process will generate the `app.js` file which is missing in your case. You can read more about this process or possibilities in laravel [here (laravel docs about frontend)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend).

Answer (score 0):

After pulling your project you need to install all dependencies using

`npm i`

Then you can build it for development one-time using

`npm run dev`

Or for real-time updates

`npm run watch`

And when your project is ready for production

`npm run prod`